# DrawImage in XP Mode or Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, gdi+, png, drawimage

I'm displaying a PNG with a transparent background that looks good in Windows 7, but then I run my app in XP Mode or remote desktop to a Windows XP machine and the PNG looks incorrect. I noticed that if I disable "Integration Mode" or run the app on XP without remote desktop, the image looks fine.

How do I get DrawImage to render the PNG correctly in XP Mode or remote desktop?

Image inside Windows 7

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/957bb6ea8b.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/957bb6ea8b.png)

Image inside XP Mode or remote desktop

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/08f1fbec46.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/08f1fbec46.png)

Here's my code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = Image.FromFile("hello.png", false);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);

    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote Desktop by default runs with 16 bit color, which I believe is incompatible with alpha blending. You need to reconfigure the display for 32 bit mode, if that's possible.

Comment: If I load and display the same image using a PictureBox control, it looks fine in XP Mode even though my DrawImage doesn't. So it seems like there must be a way to get DrawImage to render correctly despite it being 16-bit.

Comment: @simplecoder, using a PictureBox control converts the transparency to the background of the control and eliminates the alpha blending that needs to occur.